# PHP MySQLI not dieing quietly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This code:

```
$this->mysqli_connection = mysqli_connect($this->db_host,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass,$this->db_name);

if (!mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    $this->database_created = TRUE;
}
```

I'm expecting this code to just through an error quietly and I check that there is no error. However, it still outputs an error.

What I need is, if there is no database, to be able to create one. Here I'm just holding a property which can easily be checked if a database exists or not.

Is this the 'correct' way of doing this?

Comment: When I saw the title I thought to myself, "put a pillow over its face". I think I need to talk to someone about that. :/

Comment: Why do think there would be no database? And, if so - why would db user have CREATE DATABASE permission?

Comment: @JohnConde: Thanks for the laugh, you owe me a new packet of screen wipes.

Comment: its an assignment or part of. The database needs to be create in code. I completely agree, you should NEVER ever have a production website creating a database. But this isn't production, its part of uni.

Comment: You don't need supply the fourth argument, which is the dbname. You will get the error if the db does not exits. If it is not a fatal error then you can handle the error by using a custom error handler using set_error_handler and then restore it when your done. I would suggest that you ommit the db name and then query the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know whether the database exists, you should connect without specifying a database name.

```
$this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->db_host,$this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
```

Then you could either run a query for "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '{$this->db_name}'", or else just go ahead and create the database if it doesn't exist.

```
$ok = $this->mysqli->query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {$this->db_name}");
```

Then, whether you created a new database or it already existed, you still have to ready that database as the default database:

```
$ok = $this->mysqli->query("USE {$this->db_name}");
```

I agree with the comments that you wouldn't do this needless overhead for a production site. You should just have created the database prior to the PHP script running, and don't test for existence of the database on every request. But I understand your statement that this is just for an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$this->mysqli = mysqli_connect($this->db_host,$this->db_user, $this->db_pass);

$res = $this->mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$this->db_name'");
if ($res->fetch_row())
{
    $this->mysqli->select_db($this->db_name);
} else {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

    $q = mysqli_query($con, 'SHOW DATABASES');

    $dbName = 'dbname';
    $dbExists = false;

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
        if($row['Database'] == $dbName){
            $dbExists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```